# Context-Menu on right click in the threejs scene?

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, 3d, contextmenu

I have an angular project wherein the three representation is using threeJs. I wish to add a context menu on right-click to the scene. This is what I have so far. I am also receiving an error called 'menu does not exist'.

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e: MouseEvent) => { this.rightClickContextMenu(e); }, false);
        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        } else {
            (<any>document).attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function () {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
            });
        }

public rightClickContextMenu(e: MouseEvent): void {
        var rightclick;
        if (!event) var event = window.event;
        if ((<any>event).which) rightclick = ((<any>event).which == 3);
        else if ((<any>event).button) rightclick = ((<any>event).button == 2);
        if (!rightclick) return;


        const x = e.clientX - this.rect.left;
        const y = e.clientY - this.rect.top;
        var intersect;
        let scenePointer = new th.Vector2();
        scenePointer.x = (x / this.canvas.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
        scenePointer.y = (y / this.canvas.clientHeight) * - 2 + 1;

        // Determine the component in-focus using raycasting
        this.raycaster.setFromCamera(scenePointer, this.camera);

        var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);
        if (intersects.length) {
            intersect = intersects[0].object;
            menu.style.left = x + "px";
            menu.style.top = y + "px";
            menu.style.display = "";
        }
        else {
            intersect = undefined;
        }
}
```

So far, on left-click, the color of the mesh changes but nothing happens on right click. I was wondering how do I add on a context menu to the same on right click. Modifications to my code to highlight the correct one would be much appreciated from you guys. I apologise, I am very new to threejs in case this question sounds trivial.

Comment: Is your event handler being called at all on right click? Can you add the code where you attach your event handler?

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for responding. I changed the code and updated it with the information requested. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Firstly, it looks like your brackets aren't correct for your `mousedown` handler.

Also, why are you checking for `document.addEventListener` for the `contextmenu` event, but not the `mousedown` one?

If you add a console.log(e); to the first line of your `rightClickContextMenu`, what happens on right click?

Comment: Hi. I changed it to mousedown event from context menu one. Doing console log shows that it is a mouse event. However, the context menu does not appear. I guess it has something to do with the threejs.

Comment: Three.js doesn't really do anything to do with native event handlers. I'd check to see exactly what the data does as it flows through your context menu event handler

Comment: It turns out that the context menu is appearing but behind the 3D meshes. Thank you for your help so much nonetheless. I'll get the remaining part fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Stop event propagation on the control where u want this feature and then capture the event and diplay